# Pintar ruas do googlemaps

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

Estou a fazer um serviço que necessita que pinte algumas ruas dos mapas com diferentes cores consoante uma determinada tipologia.

Já o fiz para ios, como passo a demonstrar na imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas neste caso usei o mapkit da ios.

Agora quero recriar o mesmo efeito mas no googlemaps e num site em html e asp. Alguem tem ideia como o poderei fazer?

No ios o que fiz foi criar um array de coordenadas e valor e conforme o valor ele pinta a rua de uma certa cor tendo em conta as coordenadas que lhe dou. Neste caso não faço a minima ideia como o poderei fazer.

Obrigado

Comment: Tem com javascript. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?hl=pt-br

Comment: É isso mesmo. Obrigado, tanto que procurei na documentação da google e não encontrei.

Comment: De nada, precisando estamos aí.